# How can I play just the audio on YouTube on Nightbot

Tags: youtube, twitch.tv

I want to stream with the song request using Nightbot an add-on for twitch , but when the music starts in the twitch client, it starts like any YouTube video: with video and audio.

Can I play songs from Nightbot without video?

Comment: I'm not familiar with what you're using, but why not minimize the window that it opens in? Or perhaps putting the window off screen of what's being recorded?

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

> Usage
>
> ```
> !songs request Youtube or SoundCloud Link / Search Term
> ```
>
> Will use the link or search term supplied to add a song to the queue.
>   If YouTube or SoundCloud has been disabled in the song request
>   settings, they cannot be used to request songs.

or check this out the Nightbot Docs link (it can be very useful)- https://docs.nightbot.tv/commands/songs